# как сделать что бы массив печатался в обратном порядке

Tags: c, строки

```
#include<stdio.h>
void printDigit (int x, char *m, int N) //перевод цифры
{

char c[]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
int i;
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{

    *m++=c[x%N];
    x=x/N;

}
    *m='\0';
}




int main ()             
{
    FILE* tab;
    char x2[11], y16[11], zN[11] ; 
    char *x=x2, *y=y16,*z=zN;
    int i;
    int N=21;
    tab = fopen("G:\\tab.txt","w");//Путь к файлу, режим записи
    if (!tab) printf("\n-=[ФАЙЛ НЕ УДАЛОСЬ ОТКРЫТЬ]=-\n");
    fprintf(tab,"%2i\t|%10i\t|%10i\t|%10i\n",10,2,16,21);
    for (i=1;i<26;i++)
    {

        printDigit(i,x,2);
        printDigit(i,y,16);
        printDigit(i,z,N);
        fprintf(tab,"%4i\t|%10s\t|%10s\t|%10s\n",i,x2,y16,zN);
    }
    fclose(tab);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А нельзя подробнее-понятнее, что вы хотите? Какой массив вывести в обратном порядке?

Comment: получается данная функция используется в печати таблице в которой отражаются системы счисления например 10 в двоичной системе, проблема в том что он записывает результат в массив и необходимо что массив с результатом выводился в обратном порядке

Comment: Тогда зачем вы показываете эту функцию?... Есть массив `m` длиной `len` - выводите посимвольно `for(int i = len-1; i >= 0; --i) putchar(m[i]);` Вам это нужно или что-то иное?

Comment: исправила вопрос, получается на картинке число 25 в 16с\с это 19 а он выводит массив с 0 элемента, а хотелось бы узнать как выводить с 10

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего - разворачивайте строку:

```
char * reverse(char* m)
{
    for(int i = 0, j = strlen(m)-1; i < j; ++i, --j)
    {
        char c = m[i]; m[i] = m[j]; m[j] = c;
    }
    return m;
}

void printDigit (int x, char *m, int N) //перевод цифры
{
    char * n = m;
    .....
    *m='\0';
    reverse(n);
}
```

Comment: увы не работает

Comment: Ну чуточку подумать, а? Да, согласен, прокололся, но неужели так трудно исправить такую мелочь? :) см. ответ...

Comment: @Bluecookies До сих пор не заработало, или благодарность имет границы?